# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on JSP Pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was getting out of memory error on a spring framework application. I disabled a few filters (like security filter). But now the error is coming on JSP Pages. My JSP pages are quite heavy and use Tile Framework.

Unfortunately the hosting I have is providing only 32 MB of heap space and I could not increase that.

I have added a few lines in my layout page:

```java
final long  MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

// Get current size of heap in bytes
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
out.println("Total Memory (MB): "+(heapSize / MEGABYTE ));

// Get maximum size of heap in bytes. The heap cannot grow beyond this size.
// Any attempt will result in an OutOfMemoryException.
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
out.println("<br/>Heap Max Size (MB): "+(heapMaxSize / MEGABYTE ));

// Get amount of free memory within the heap in bytes. This size will increase
// after garbage collection and decrease as new objects are created.
long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
out.println("<br/>Heap Free Size (MB): "+(heapFreeSize / MEGABYTE ));
```

The above prints following output at output (HTML Page)

```
Total Memory (MB): 29 
Heap Max Size (MB): 29 
Heap Free Size (MB): 3
```

Here is the stack trace:

```java
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException in '/jsp/fragments/account/newAccount.jsp': java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:921)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:460)
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.tiles.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f3(layout_jsp.java:818)
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.tiles.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:428)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: What is your question? I think we would need some code to be able to help you.

Comment: My question is that i want to get rid from Out of Heapspace error even on 32 MB of space by using some best practices of JSP that reduce memory space or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

> *I have is providing only 32 MB of heap space and I could not increase that.*.

Sorry, but then that's the end of story. You have 2 options:

- Rewrite your views to be more memory efficient. Perhaps you need to fall back to plain vanilla JSP/Servlet without any additional frameworks which each of course needs their own memory share.
- Give the server more memory. Upgrade your existing hosting account or migrate to a different host.

Answer (score 2):

Profiling your application could be one option which will give you insight into what actually is causing an OutOfMemory error and if it is really possible to optimize the code without increasing the physical memory.